# Getting envelope of all features in feature class using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, extents

How do I get a single envelope of all the features in a feature class using ArcMap?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the [Minimum Bounding Geometry](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/minimum-bounding-geometry.htm) tool which:

> Creates a feature class containing polygons which represent a
> specified minimum bounding geometry enclosing each input feature or
> each group of input features.

Specify the "ALL" for the group option to get a single feature representing the envelope of your features.

Answer (score 5):

FeatureClass supports the IGeoDataset interface, which has an Extent property containing the IEnvelope used by all features.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the arcgisscripting Python module in 9.3x:

```
import arcgisscripting

gp = arcgisscripting.create(9.3)

fc = "C:/workshop/exercises/exercise1/data/stlouis_cities_geog.shp"

fcDesc = gp.describe(fc)

shpExtent = fcDesc.extent
print("Bounding Box: " + str(shpExtent.XMin) + "," + str(shpExtent.YMin) + "," +  str(shpExtent.XMax) + "," + str(shpExtent.YMax))

del fc, gp
```

Answer (score 1):

At 9.3 you can use the Feature Envelope to Polygon tool. You may need to dissolve the output into a multi-part feature then run the Envelope tool again.

Answer (score 0):

A rough hack: In your Dataframe Properties, Data Frame tab, Extent Used By Full Extent Command - Go to Other|Specify Extent, select Outline of Features and the FC of interest. OK out of all dialogs, go back in to the Specify Extent, and the extent of your FC should now be what is displayed in the Custom Extent top, right, bottom, left fields. We do this to set the custom full extent in ArcGIS Server map services, but it should get you the extent of the FC you want.